# Cross referencing: Print reference object

Tags: cross-referencing

I use the `LaTeX` article template `scifile`. When I do a cross reference to a Figure, only the Figure number gets printed out.

E.g. when I do: `see: \ref{fig:1}` i only get `see: 1` instead of `see: Figure 1`.

How can I fix this behaviour to print out the reference form (e.g. equation, section, figure, table etc.)?

I have tried to search for reference style management, but I found no solution for editing the cross-reference output style.

Comment: Maybe `\autoref{}` from the `hyperref` package is what you are looking for.

Comment: Either `autoref` from `hyperref` or `cleveref`'s `\cref` features can be used (use `cleveref` as last package, even after `hyperref`

Answer (score 2):

In a standard setup, `\ref` does only print the number, but not the reference type.

The package `cleveref` provides `\cref` (or `\Cref`) to print both the label type and the referenced value. For standard counters such as `figure`, `table` all is set up already, even language aware.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{figure one}\label{figone}
\end{figure}

In \cref{figone} or in \Cref{figone}
\end{document}
```

[image]